# ¿Porque wordpress no refleja los cambios?

Tags: wordpress

He realizado cambios en mi archivo front-page.php para incluir MetaSlider pero el sitio no se actualiza, solo muestra un slider que yo habia programado por medio de jquery.

Ademas, probe agregar un nuevo item al menu y tampoco se muestra y luego cambie el tema y solo la pagina de portada no aplico el nuevo tema (aun conserva el tema anterior) las demas paginas si aplicaron el nuevo tema pero no muestran el menu que anteriormente cree.

Quiero aclarar que no uso ningun plugin de cache.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos

Comment: Tal ves solo `ctrl + f5` así carga todos los datos de tu navegador desde 0

Comment: ¿No tendrás Cloudfare activado en tu sitio? Guarda por un tiempo una caché antigua de las páginas de tu sitio, para ver los cambios debes resetear la caché al menos de esa página.